# get content of an iframe in angular

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I can display the result of a RSS in iframe, I would like to read the content.
But cannot figure out how to select the text in the iframe.

here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ykLVns30qnRR6wx8lu8d?p=preview

selecting by tags like below will not work.

```
angular.element('#iframeID');
```

**Edit:**
Spend some time researching and finally found the answer, you cannot access the document in an iframe or a div that loads data from another page. Because of Cross Origin Policy.

Comment: you can't access a cross domain iframe and if you could your approach isn't correct

Comment: I have injected sce in the real code. not on the plunker. I know the correct approach is through api, but what if it isn't an option and i can only do it this way?

Comment: If it's an RSS feed, I would look for alternate ways to access the data...assuming that it is indeed a cross domain iframe. One handy tool is YQL, can get it returned in JSON for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  angular.element('#iframeID').contents();
```

This is just jquery - not angular.